# A problem {came up | showed up} in my phone?

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

Since last few days

> a problem came up in my phone

or

> a problem showed up in my phone.

which is more correct?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use either sentence; instead, I would say "I've been having problems with my phone".

Out of the two sentences, the latter is better, but not too elegant.

Comment: +1 for not saying either of those. Other natural expressions include: *Something's wrong with my phone* and *My phone's been acting up* and *I have a problem with my phone.*

Comment: Or, idiomatically, _My phone is [on the fritz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_fritz)_ (though that might sound a little dated).

Answer (score 0):

> A problem came up **with** my phone
>   A problem showed up **on** my phone

Both sentences **mean the same** that there has been a problem with your phone.
People will tend to use **came up** and **showed up** interchangeably in your context.

There might be a very slight difference in usage

**Came up** can also refer to the non-visual use of your phone:

> memory storage
>   software upgrading
>   buttons not working
>   loss of signal
>   running apps
>
> A problem **came up** with the app because it was corrupted
>   The problem **came up** after I lost connection
>   The problem with the buttons **came up** when I tried to take a picture

when the problem can occur without any action on your part

**Showed up** can be used to talk about a problem that was observable

> The problem **showed up** after the upgrade

However, usually people will say

> I have a problem **with** my phone
>   I've been having problems **with** my phone